# Jquery Droppable Drop an item not at last

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-droppable

I ve this combination of droppable draggable HTML elements

droppable

```
$( "#contenitore" ).droppable({
  hoverClass: "drag-over_ca",
  tolerance: 'pointer',
   greedy: true,
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
  $(ui.draggable).appendTo( this );
   }
});
```

draggable

```
 $( "div.element-container" ).draggable({
    cursorAt: { left: 92, top: 50} ,
    cursor: "move",
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone", 
    appendTo: "body", 
     drag: function(event, ui) {

   $(this).css({opacity:0.4});
  $(ui.helper).addClass("handled");
        },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
  $(ui.helper).removeClass("handled");
  $(this).css({opacity:1});
    }
});
```

that works fine, but the dropped elemente put ever dropped at the last of list.
How can drop an element at top of list or beetwen other element of the list.

n.b.

I need directly drop element at first or beetwen, 
and not drop at last and switch the order after with sortable.

Comment: Its always at the end because you use `appendTo`. That's what it does ! What if you combine draggable with sortable ? http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable. Make your droppable also draggable and limit it to itself.

Comment: this solution cause a incredible fastidious flikering beetwen item  in the container, because the container contain an other kind of item sortable.

Answer (score 1):

Make your div.element-container draggable + sortable. You can do it like -

```
$("div.element-container").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#contenitore",
    cursorAt: { left: 92, top: 50} ,
    cursor: "move",
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone", 
    appendTo: "body", 
     drag: function(event, ui) {

   $(this).css({opacity:0.4});
  $(ui.helper).addClass("handled");
        },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
  $(ui.helper).removeClass("handled");
  $(this).css({opacity:1});
    }
});

$("#contenitore").sortable({
      revert: true
});
```

Comment: the containe is already sortable becouse contains an other kind of item, and if i connect all this solution cause a incredible fastidious flikering beetwen item in the container.

Comment: You should remove droppable to #contenitore. Droppable is not needed in your condition. Look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abzYK/206/)

Comment: i need droppable for recognize some event that only droppable have,for execute other necessary function. And droppable prevent  flikering beetwen item in the container.

Comment: but your example in   jsfiddle semms interesting

Comment: but i ve not 2 different container, i ve only one container and 2 different kinds of item will draggend and droppend only in it